# How to avoid permissions issues when using PHP to create folders and store files?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, php, nginx

I have a Laravel project and part of the code creates folders and stores photos inside it.

Each user has his own folder, but if he did not upload anything yet then this folder does not exist.

Then the PHP script creates this folder and saves the photos inside.

The PHP script creates the folder and successfully saves the files there by the user id path: `/storage/files/<user_id>/some_file`

But, I no longer have permission for that newly created folder so I believe I won't be able to access it later.

Currently in order to check view the folders created for testing purposes I manually run the following every time:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage
chmod -R 775 storage
```

But how can I make the PHP script run properly with correct permissions?

I am using nginx in Ubuntu Server 22.04

Comment: are user directories (`/storage/files/<user_id>`) precreated?

Comment: Nope, they are created when the user uploads photos for the first time. You think I should change this behavior? If it helps I can try

Comment: Set group for files as `www-data`, `chown:www-data files` (presuming that is the GID nginx runs under) and make `files` setgid, `chmod 2775 files`. Now all directories created under `files` will be owned by GID `www-data` and should allow the web server write permissions. When you look at the permissions for the `files` directory it will be `drwxrwsr-x`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin if in order to be able to see the created folder I use `sudo chown -R $USER:www-data storage`, does it mean that because nginx creates the folder in another group, then my user has no permission therefore it works only after I `chown` it with my user to view it(Just trying to understand the basics)? How can I check what GID nginx runs under?

Comment: Yes, that is my read. By making the base directory before PHP creates new ones setgid to the group the web server runs as, that should provide write permission below `files` for the web server (through PHP or whatever you like) There should be a space in `chown :www-data files` above -- missed that.

Comment: Thanks! There is just something that confuses me because I'm not proficient with Linux: Currently, all the files and folders in the project are accessible both by my user and by nginx (Because I can view the files, and also nginx can serve them). So what exactly happens when PHP creates new folders? Maybe it is actually owned by nginx already but not by my user? And the issue is only the permissions for my user, not nginx. Because the files are successfully created, it's just that my user can't view them unless I run `sudo chown -R $USER:www-data`

Comment: If the files are successfully created and the user cannot read them, then that is a read permission issue. If you don't want the files world-readable (that should be fine if the read access is controlled by the web server), then the files will need to be readable by the user. (as your use of `$USER`). I don't do a lot of PHP, but it should be able to change the user to `$USER` if it has user-write permissions. Your web server will run as a specific user and group, If `files` is set to both, e.g. `chown www:www-data`, then PHP should be able to change the owner to `$USER`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin thanks! You meant `chown www-data:www-data` not `www:www-data` right? Also just realized that the project is owned by my user name and group, and files created by the server are owned by `www-data` user and group. So you were correct. I assume in this case, I will need to change the entire project ownership group to `www-data:www-data`, and add my user to `www-data` group with correct r/w permissions?

Comment: It depends what your web server runs as. I can check SUSE (`www:www-run`) and Archlinux (`http:http`), but you will have to check for your specific distribution. Many use different web-users and web-groups. You can see SUSE does, but Arch doesn't.